# Refresh token rotation vs silent authentication

Tags: authentication, oauth, frontend, access-token, refresh-token

I am seeing a lot of conflicting information out there about the refresh token rotation strategy being the new hotness and replacing silent authentication when it comes to updating expired access tokens but I have a few questions.

- Is it more secure than silent auth? And if so why?
- What's the standard for storing a refresh token on a web app (node server & client)?

  - I am assuming it would be encoded in a JWE along with the access token then in a secure http-only cookie?

Assuming that I am correct that you need to encode the refresh token and place it in a cookie I feel that creates some questionable security implications for applications spread across subdomains sharing that same cookie because they are all forced to use the same auth client and secret used to sign the JWE so they can decode it serverside.

Also for access tokens used across sub domains the refresh token strategy doesn't really work as it will just refresh the initial issued access token for app one (app-one.acme.com) but as soon as the user navigates to app two (app-two.acme.com) that access token may not have the necessary scopes to access the resources for that app.

The Auth0 docs are a little vague about refresh tokens vs silent auth implementation so would be interested to hear your thoughts also any resources you can point me to would also be great.

Comment: No doubt this question will be closed. You should try to ask 1 question, not several and ideally if you use terminology from a vendor link to it's definitions. Generally I would suggest to read OAuth2 documents and drafts. This draft in particular should address some of your questions: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps . If it doesn't, open more questions here and be more specific.

Comment: Certainly not a crime David, but it is a rule for this site! Also note I neither downvoted nor voted this question for closure, I'm just letting you know what will likely happen when others run into this question and hopefully set you up to get the best possible results from this website. I don't agree with all the rules.

Comment: Also, the link I provided is totally worth reading. Trying to be helpful, don't take it personally.